# Connecting Excel to Snowflake

Tags: excel, vba, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to establish ODBC connection to Snowflake using VBA. Unfortunately getting the following error:

[image]

My company is using OneLogin to authenticate Snowflake users - when I am trying to connect using Power Query (ODBC connector) then web browser window pops up (SAML Response for Snowflake), after closing web browser window I am able to connect to Snowflake database.

I suppose that the problem with VBA comes down to this web browser window popping up. Is there a way to overcome this in VBA code? Or maybe  problem lies in something else?

This is the code I tried:

```
 Sub test()

    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ConnectionString As String
    Dim StrQuery As String
    Dim POL As Range
    
    With Application
            .EnableEvents = False
            .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

        
        ConnectionString = "DRIVER={SnowflakeDSIIDriver};" & _
                           "SERVER=xxxxxxxx" & _
                           "DATABASE=xxxxxx" & _
                           "SCHEMA=EXT_xxxxxxxx" & _
                           "WAREHOUSE=xxxxxxxxx" & _
                           "ROLE=xxxxxxxxx" & _
                           "UID=xxxxxxxxxxx" & _
                           "PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxx" & _
                           "Authenticator=externalbrowser"

        cnn.Open ConnectionString
        cnn.CommandTimeout = 300

    Set POL = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    StrQuery = POL.Value
    rst.Open StrQuery, cnn
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A200000").CopyFromRecordset rst
    
    Set rst = Nothing
    
    Set cnn = Nothing
    Set rst = Nothing
    
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    

End Sub
```

When debugging, error points out into part with connection settings.

Comment: Code has been included in the post.

Comment: Can you maybe try for ConnectionString only this: **ConnectionString = "Driver={SnowflakeDSIIDriver};Server=xxxx.snowflakecomputing.com;Port=443;authenticator=externalbrowser;UID=xxxxxxx;"** where UID is the email address/user for your OneLogin.

Comment: @Sergiu, the same issue.

Comment: Would you be able to generate [ODBC log](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-generate-log-file-on-Snowflake-connectors#ODBC) and provide a snippet from that log? The error itself would mean you either have a proxy or firewall in between that breaks the SSL connection, but the fact that it works with PowerQuery makes me think there is more than that.

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately I am not able to generate the ODBC log by myself. Do you know maybe how to overcome SAML authentication in VBA?

Answer (score 1):

```
  " Using Key Pair Authentication worked fine form me:
                  ConnectionString = "DRIVER={SnowflakeDSIIDriver};" & _
                       "SERVER=XXXX.snowflakecomputing.com;" & _
                       "UID=XXXUSER;" & _
                       "DATABASE=DBXXX;" & _
                       "SCHEMA=SCXXXXXX;" & _
                       "WAREHOUSE=WHXXXX;" & _
                       "ROLE=RLXXXXXX;" & _
                       "AUTHENTICATOR=SNOWFLAKE_JWT;" & _
                       "PRIV_KEY_FILE=\Path\rsa_key_xxxx.p8;" & _
                       "PRIV_KEY_FILE_PWD=pwrxxxxxxx;" & _
                       "TRACING=0;""
```

Answer (score 0):

The option **authenticator=externalbrowser** is why you are getting the window popup. To avoid the popup, select an alternative authentication method. [Key Pair Authentication](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/key-pair-auth.html) is commonly used for secure connections in this scenario.